# 64-bit Linux performance issue with memset

Tags: c, linux, performance, 32bit-64bit

I'm debugging an application that is running quite a bit slower when built as a 64-bit Linux ELF executable than as a 32-bit Linux ELF executable. Using Rational (IBM) Quantify, I tracked much of the performance difference down to (drum roll...) `memset`. Oddly, `memset` is taking a **lot** longer in the 64-bit executable.

I am even able to see this with a small, simple application:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFER_LENGTH 8000000

int main()
{
  unsigned char* buffer = malloc(BUFFER_LENGTH * sizeof(unsigned char));
  for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    memset(buffer, 0, BUFFER_LENGTH * sizeof(unsigned char));
}
```

I build like this:
`$ gcc -m32 -std=gnu99 -g -O3 ms.c`
and
`$ gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -g -O3 ms.c`

The wall-clock time as reported by `time` is longer for the `-m64` build and Quantify confirms that the extra time is being spent in `memset`.

So far I've tested in VirtualBox and VMWare (but not bare-metal Linux; I realize I need to do that next). The amount of extra time spent seems to vary a bit from one system to the next.

What's going on here? Is there a well-known issue that my Google-foo is not able to uncover?

**EDIT:** The disassembly (`gcc ... -S`) on my system shows that `memset` is being invoked as an external function:

32-bit:

```
.LBB2:
    .loc 1 14 0
    movl    $8000000, 8(%esp)
    .loc 1 12 0
    addl    $1, %ebx
    .loc 1 14 0
    movl    $0, 4(%esp)
    movl    %esi, (%esp)
    call    memset
```

64-bit:

```
.LBB2:
    .loc 1 14 0
    xorl    %esi, %esi
    movl    $8000000, %edx
    movq    %rbp, %rdi
.LVL1:
    .loc 1 12 0
    addl    $1, %ebx
    .loc 1 14 0
    call    memset
```

---

System:

- CentOS 5.7 2.6.18-274.17.1.el5 x86_64
- GCC 4.1.2
- Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2600K CPU @ 3.40GHz / VirtualBox
  (discrepancy is worse on a Xeon E5620 @ 2.40GHz / VMWare)

Comment: What architecture is this? What processor model? Can we see some disassembly?

Comment: On my box running bare-metal 64-bit Ubuntu with gcc 4.4.5, the run time of the two builds in indistinguishable.

Comment: @Mysticial - I added some system details. How would you suggest getting disassembly that includes `memset`? Of course `gcc -S` will just show the call to memset.

Comment: @DavidCitron Actually, `memset()` is a compiler internal. Most of the time, it gets inlined and doesn't compile to a function call.

Comment: @Mysticial: For reference, my `gcc 4.4.5` does not inline `memset()` in the OP's code (regardless of `-m32`/`-m64`).

Comment: I also get identical timings on Ubuntu via VirtualBox on Windows. Core i7 870.

Comment: I get better perf with -m64 than -m32 here (with both gcc 4.4 and gcc 4.1). Processor is "Quad-Core AMD Opteron(tm) Processor 2384", not virtualized.

Comment: @Mysticial I added the dissasembly above ... so why is it "calling" it?

Comment: That's interesting, it doesn't inline in MSVC either. I think the test size is large enough for the compiler to not need to inline it.

Comment: Just tested on Core i7 2600K @ 4.4 GHz - Win7 x64 VS2010. x86: `4.383`, x64: `3.931`. Faster on x64.

Comment: @DavidCitron, I'd test on the same machines and without VirtualBox/VMWare to remove them from the picture.

Comment: @DavidCitron: What are the actual run times that you're seeing with the two versions?

Comment: It is utterly pointless to write sizeof([unsigned] char), it is always 1 *by definition*.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that on my non-virtualized Mandriva Linux system the x86_64 version is slightly (about 7%) slower. In both cases the `memset()` library function is called, regardless of the instruction set word size.

A casual look at the assembly code of both library implementations reveals that the x86_64 version is *significantly* more complex. I assume that this has mostly to do with the fact that the 32-bit version has to deal with only 4 possible alignment cases, versus the 8 possible alignment cases of the 64-bit version. It also seems that the x86_64 `memset()` loop has been more extensively unrolled, perhaps due to different compiler optimizations.

Another factor that could account for the slower operations is the increased I/O load associated with the use of a word size of 64 bits. Both code and metadata (pointers e.t.c.) generally get larger in 64-bit applications.

Also, keep in mind that the library implementations included in most distributions are targeted to whatever CPU the maintainers consider to be the current lowest common denominator for each processor family. This may leave the 64-bit processors at a disadvantage, since the 32-bit instruction set has been stable for some time now.

Comment: Handling alignment should only affect the array boundary, which is a minor complication in case of a 8MB array.

Comment: @zvrba: It *is* measurable and consistent as far as I can tell: 32b: 9.487s, 64b: 10.134s

Comment: Even a larger difference here on real hardware (Xeon W3520, Debian amd64): 32b: 5.5s, 64b: 6.5s. Note that -O0/O1/O2/O3 barely changes anything.

Comment: How many measurements? What is their distribution? (I'm curious about whether there are outliers and how large they are.)

Comment: @zvrba Maybe 12 measurements on each, plus the -O variations. Distribution stdev < 0.1s.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that virtualization is the culprit: I have been running some benchmarks on my own (random number generation in bulk, sequential searches; also 64-bit) and found out that the code runs ~2x slower within Linux in VirtualBox than natively under windows. The funny thing is, the code does no I/O (except simple printf now and then, *in between* timings) and uses little memory (all data fits into L1 cache), so one could think that you could exclude page table management and TLB overheads.

This is mysterious indeed. I have noticed that VirtualBox reports to the VM that SSE 4.1 and SSE 4.2 instructions are not supported, even though the CPU supports them, and the program using them runs fine(!) in a VM. I have no time to investigate the issue further, but you REALLY should time it on a real machine.  Unfortunately, my program won't run on 32 bits, so I couldn't test for slowdown in 32-bit mode.

Answer (score 0):

When compiling your example code the compiler sees the fixed block size (~8MB) and decides to use the library version. Try code for much smaller blocks (for memset'ing just a few bytes) - compare the disassembly.

Though I do not know why the x64 version is slower. I guess there is an issue in your time measurement code.

From the [changelog of gcc 4.3](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.3/changes.html):

> Code generation of block move (memcpy) and block set (memset) was rewritten. GCC can now pick the best algorithm (loop, unrolled loop, instruction with rep prefix or a library call) based on the size of the block being copied and the CPU being optimized for. A new option -minline-stringops-dynamically has been added. With this option string operations of unknown size are expanded such that small blocks are copied by in-line code, while for large blocks a library call is used. This results in faster code than -minline-all-stringops when the library implementation is capable of using cache hierarchy hints. The heuristic choosing the particular algorithm can be overwritten via -mstringop-strategy. Newly also memset of values different from 0 is inlined.

Hope this explains what the compiler designers try to do (even if this is for another version) ;-)